# Slowly increasing sequence and convergence in the sense of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\{ \beta_n \}$ be a slowly increasing complex sequence. That is, there exists $M > 0$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|\beta_n| \le C(1+ |n|)^k$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Let $g_n$ be given by
$$g_n(t) = \beta_n e^{2\pi i n t} $$
Show that $g_n$ converges to $0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ in the sense of distributions.

My attempt:
$$|T_{g_n}(\phi) - 0| = |\int_\mathbb{R} \beta_n e^{2\pi i nt}\phi(t)dt| \le \int_\mathbb{R} |\beta_n e^{2\pi i nt}| |\phi(t)|dt \le ||\phi(t)||_\infty \int_\mathbb{R}|C(1+|n|)^ke^{2\pi i n t}|dt$$
$$\le ||\phi(t)||_\infty |C(1+|n|)^k| \int_\mathbb{R} |e^{2\pi i n t}|dt $$
But I'm not sure where to go from here, or if I've gone in the wrong direction from the beginning.

Comment: The first inequality is what got you in trouble. Don't put $|\cdot|$ inside the integral. Use integration(s) by part. Also, get rid of the $\beta_n$ which are a distraction.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @AbdelmalekAbdesselam. Is there any chance you could elaborate a bit more? I'm still stuck on this problem. Any help would be great!